# Vertical middle for an element within a variable height container

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation:

[image]

A variable height div (#container) with an image on the inside (image that is placed within another div) that I need to float:right **and** align vertically in the middle. How to do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Maybe I didn't make it clear enough that i *do not know beforehand* how much content the container has, from a few lines to a wall of text, so any solution relying on its height won't work (and that's my problem :P)

This is a fiddle with an example of possible content to which align the image: http://jsfiddle.net/9DbmN/

Comment: Did you checked this - http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: in the exmple they have a set height (400px) so everything relative to it works. i can get my problem solved setting a fixed height for the container, but the problem is that i don't know beforehand how much content will it contain.

Comment: what about this http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/a82Qv/

Comment: @pistacchio - just remove the height from that example, it still works - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/sRLXp/)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) by Chris Coyier. Imo it´s a pretty solid solution to the holy grail of vertical centering.

Comment: thanks, but the problem that I find with the proposed solution (very elegant indeed) is when the container itself has other content together with the box to align)

Answer (score 0):

I would not discourage using tables here))) If you use a two-cell table with `vertical-align: middle` set on its `td` elements - it will perfectly (and easily!!!) solve your problem.

If you want to have two containers, one of which (the one with the image) will be floated to the right and needed centering - I'd say you'll have to avoid using `float` property for this. Because a) as far as I understand you don't need you content on the left to be UNDER the image, right? b) floats are block-level elements and you can't change it even if you set `display: table-cell`, the browser will still render it as `display: block` - which leads me to the conclusion that you won't manage to center it by css (at least by the means I'm aware of).

If you don't need ie7 support a possible workaround might be this:

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">Content goes here, vertically aligned with the image</div>
    <div class="i_used_to_be_floated_right">Image goes here</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.content, .i_used_to_be_floated_right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
    background: green;
    width: 80%;
}
.i_used_to_be_floated_right{
    background: red;
    width: 20%;
}
```

The working example live can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/sDXMj/1/

But if you need ie7 - I would vote for the table-solution I stated at the very beginning.